# Is this faster than 2 for loops for iterating through a 2D array, or is it the same speed?

Tags: java, arrays

```
for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
        map[x][y] = new Plot(x, y, "map");
        if (x == 199 && y < 199) {
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
    }
```

I have this code here that I set up to create a 2D array of 200x200 objects for a map, and I would like to know if it is the same speed or if it indeed runs faster. I'm trying to optimize the array creation.

Thanks!

**EDIT : assuming Y starts at 0, and height is 200 always** 
**EDIT 2 : Thank you to everybody who answered :D Yes I could've created something to test it, but eh**

Comment: assuming Y starts at 0, and height is 200 always

Comment: Did you time them?

Comment: no.............

Comment: If there is any speed difference at all, it should be minuscule. If you want to optimize it, you should look at your object creation and see if you can make that faster.

Comment: Not faster and less readable. Just-In-Time compilation will have more problems with this code, and never kick in.

Comment: @Lokesh It's obvious how they're iterating through the array - it's equivalent to `for (y=0;y<200;++y) for (x=0;x<200;++x) map[x][y] = new Plot(x, y, "map"); --y;`

Comment: @user234461 Oh !! sorry yea y < 199. I misread the code

Comment: @Lokesh No, `y` will increment every time x is 199, provided `y` is less than 199! Read the code again :-) However, OP's code will get stuck in an infinite loop because `x` will never exceed ` height` if `height` is 200 - it'll keep getting reset to 0 ad infinitum, which is a problem.

Comment: @user234461 I already got that, read my comment again.

Comment: @Lokesh Looks like a lack of synchronisation on my part resulted in a data race. Sorry about that! Or maybe you edited your comment? >_>

Comment: @user234461 :) I guess you can make out something with the last time I edited my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generated code will not be faster - the instructions generated will be almost identical; in fact, when compiler optimisations are turned on, the compiler might struggle to optimise either loop effectively because it can't recognise them as simple loops.

The vast majority of the execution time will be spent allocating the new memory, and writing pointers to the `map` arrays. In fact, one potential improvement does leap out: at the moment, you're accessing the `map` arrays like this:

```
map[0][0]
map[1][0]
map[2][0]
...
map[0][1]
map[1][1]
map[2][1]
...
map[0][2]
```

and so on.

This is undesirable, because the addresses are far apart in memory. It is always better to access memory in such a way that addresses that are close to each other are accessed near to each other in time, because this is much friendlier to the cache.

So if you were to swap the order of iteration round (e.g. `[0][0], [0][1], [0][2], ... [1][0], [1][1], [1][2]...`) then you *might* find your code runs quicker - or you might not; it all depends on the architecture of the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about it, if you have i.e. 200*200 array and you want to put some new instance into each of it, you have to do it in every single "cell" = 40000 cells. You cant be better than that no matter the optimization.

Even if you dont have for-cycle and do it with

```
x[0][0] = ...
x[0][1] = ...
```

You still have to write 40000 commands